# Query en Azure, ¿cómo especificar las columnas?

Tags: sql, azure

Quiero que solamente me inserte en mi tabla los registros con fecha mayor a la indicada. Pero la sintaxis es errónea. Tengo la sensación de que no he especificado correctamente la columna (fecha_creacion) ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualización:
he probado la sintaxis de Frank: INSERT INTO GENERAL_LEDGER_SSISDB SELECT * FROM GENERAL_LEDGER_SSISDB WHERE fecha_creacion >= '2021-11-23'   pero me da el siguiente error "A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause"

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Me da la impresión que ese debería ser un Query de consulta, no de inserción.

Comment: Hola Carmen el tema es de sintaxis es un insert de un select por lo cual tu consulta deberia quedar asi :  `INSERT INTO GENERAL_LEDGER_SSISDB
SELECT * FROM GENERAL_LEDGER_SSISDB
WHERE fecha_creacion >= '2021-11-23'`  siempre y cuando los datos los quieras extraer de la misma tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias , Frank, pero me da el siguiente error:  A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause